# Collecting data from a webform

Tags: shopify, information-retrieval

I'm creating a online form to collect competition entries for shopify. I've written the code below and get a "page not found' repsonse when clicking the submit button. I'm guessing thats becuase i need to direct the repsonse but how and where do i do that?

Do i need to create another page to thank the customer for the entry? Also how do i know where the repsonses go?

Code is

Full name: 
 
 Email Address: 
 
 What's the capacity of the CAT Wheelbarrow?

thank you!

I've tried adding in url but I'm kinda lost